# Solving equation System

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I've been trying to solve this equation, but I can't get it. There's a term in the equation, $m(9.81)$, and can't handle it with the other terms of the equation. And $F_{AB} = 1000$.

$$
\begin{gather}
-\frac{2}{7} F_{AB} - \frac{1}{3} F_{AC} + \frac{3}{5} F_{AD} = 0 \\
\frac{3}{7} F_{AB} - \frac{2}{3} F_{AC} - \frac{4}{5} F_{AD} = 0 \\
\frac{6}{7} F_{AB} + \frac{2}{3} F_{AC} - m(9.81) = 0
\end{gather}
$$

For reference, the original image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBkza.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eq.1 $-\frac12 $ Eq. 2 eliminates $F_{AC}$ and gives  $F_{AD}=500$. Then you can compute  $F_{AC}=\frac{300}7$ from the first equation, and finally the third equation will give you $m$.

Comment: tanks so much I have solved the same way too jajaja

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given that you know one of the terms already ($F_{AB} = 1000$), the system reduces to 3 variables: $F_{AC}$, $F_{AD}$, and $m$. Then you can find $F_{AC}$ and $F_{AD}$ with the first 2 equations, and then finally $m$ with the last.

Comment: thanks I solved the same way you did